# select2 remote data json

Tags: jquery, json, jquery-select2

I am using Select2 and I managed to code this. However, I cannot retrieve the results.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {
         $(".js-data-example-ajax").select2({
          ajax: {
              url: 'https://api.github.com/search/repositories',
              dataType: 'json',
              quietMillis: 100,
              data: function (term) {
                  return {
                      q: term
                  };
              },
              results: function (data) {
                  var myResults = [];
                  $.each(data, function (index, item) {
                      myResults.push({
                          'id': item.id,
                          'text': item.name
                      });
                  });
                  return {
                      results: myResults
                  };
              }
          }
      });
});
</script>
```

for example I type `s` the request will be `https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q%5Bterm%5D=s`

Am I doing this right?

Comment: I think the request should be like `https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=s`. `https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q%5Bterm%5D=s` doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that, `term` coming to function is an object, that means you need to use `term.term` to get the exact string.

Also use `processResults`, instead of `results`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".js-data-example-ajax").select2({
    ajax: {
      url: 'https://api.github.com/search/repositories',
      dataType: 'json',
      quietMillis: 100,
      data: function(term) {
        return {
          q: term.term
        };
      },
      processResults: function(data) {
        return {
          results: $.map(data.items, function(item, index) {
            return {
              'id': item.id,
              'text': item.name
            };
          })
        };
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<select class="js-data-example-ajax">
  <option>----select----</option>
</select>
```